# select query heroku database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

How can I send select * query to heroku database?
I loged in into heroku console, and I would like to execute this query:
select * FROM refinery_pages

I'm using ruby or rails, refinery cms, heroku

Answer (score 5):

`heroku pg:psql --app yourapp`

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-starter-tier#psql-console